# overflow-y, fixed element and scrollbar nightmare

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, fixed

I have a classic page with a lot of content, and a button that open a popup. This pop can have an height bigger than my window, so i need to scroll inside my pop up. When I hide my trigger, i want to be on the exact same scroll position than before showing this pop up. I have try many solution, and... it's not exactly that :) You can see an example on JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/S6EFW/11/
I'm close, but the scroll bar goes under the menu, and i don't know how fix that... :(

You can see what i'm trying to do on the site of USA TODAY : http://www.usatoday.com/

If you scroll a bit, and click on one of the main article, a popup shows. You can scroll in this popup. When you close the popup, you're on the exact same place of the page than befor opening the popup.

I have tried to use :

```
  overflow-y:scroll;
```

But I still have problem with the scroll bar and the fixed menu... :(

If you have an idea to the way to achieve that !

Answer (score 1):

For your `#content` try with `margin` instead of `padding`:

```
#content {
  margin-top : 100px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

Check this **http://jsfiddle.net/S6EFW/18/**

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index:-999;` to your `#hello`

so:

```
#hello {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100px;
    background-color : #123456;
    z-index:-999;
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that, the text of content goes over the menu when you scroll. I've tried to add a z-index:-1000 to #content, but it doesn't work.

Comment: And most important, you can't interact with div with negative z-index. Bad idea for a menu :)